# Trying to match multiple of a word in one string

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a command for a bot I work on that's as follows :

```
.command @user @user2 (user list can grow etc..) item
```

The current regex I am using is

```
/([.command]+ [@A-Za-z0-9_?]+ [A-Za-z0-9]+)/g
```

The problem I have is that I need it to find each user instead of only the first occurrence. Ideally I'd also like to be able to target that each user starts with a "@" character.

Any help on this appreciated.

Comment: If the user should start with `@`, put it before the character set.

Comment: Same thing with the `.` before the command. Take it out of `[]`.

Comment: And on that note: don't guess at your regex, use something like https://regex101.com to make sure your patterns make sense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use

```
/^\.([a-z]+)\s+((?:@[\w?]+\s+)+)(\w+)/i
```

Capture group 1 is the command.

Capture group 2 will contain all the `@user` parameters, you can use `.split(/\s+/)` to split it into separate users.

Capture group 3 is the item at the end

Comment: This worked perfect, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

This is one (of many) solution:

```
function getUsers(command){

   var result = [];

   var index = command.indexOf("@");
   while(index>-1){
      var i1 = command.indexOf("@", index);
      var i2 = command.indexOf(" ", i1);
      if(i2==-1){i2 = command.length;}
      var user = command.substr(i1, i2-i1);
      index = command.indexOf("@", i2);
      result.push(user);
   }

   return result;

}

getUsers("cmd @a1 @a2 @a3 ckkasd @a5 a6 @a7")
```

This one dont uses regular expressions. It will consume less memory and will run faster for big strings.